# Split many single character with regex (java)

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I've got two strings: "EEFFE" and "EEFFFFFFFFFE", is there any regular expression in java such that when I use split get the following array in both strings?: {"EE","E"}.

Comment: Are you trying to return data or just match it

Comment: Do you also want to split on single `F`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex you are looking for is just `"F+"`.

```
String[] whatINeed = s.split("F+")
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution with a slightly different result:

```
String a = "EEFFE"; 
String b = a.replaceAll("F+", "");
```